# How to get email notification for every git push issued on any github hosted repo

Tags: git, github, repository

Let's say there is one github repo. (Public/Private)

Many developers are working on same repo and doing git push.

Now is there any way so once any user commits on that repo.I get email notification that user X has commited on this repo.

Usually on github we get email notification, for Pull request create/merged, Issues, Comments **But i need to email notification on every git push command issued on that repo**

Comment: Login your account > Go to https://github.com/settings/notifications > check all the email options.

Comment: @Biswapriyo It does provide emails on pull request/comments/issues not for every git push commands.

Comment: Are you talking about your personal repository or you're a member of a team or a organization?

Comment: In all  that cases, I need such notification.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps and it perfectly works fine,

https://help.github.com/articles/choosing-the-types-of-notifications-you-receive/

Comment: Github is deprecating services so this will stop working in Jan 2019

Comment: it's dec 2020 and this still works.. !!